# Is it appropriate to refer to the definite integral of $f$ from $a$ to $b$ even though $f$ is just defined on $(a,b)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, terminology

Suppose we have a function $f\colon (a,b)\to\mathbb R$ that is both continuous and bounded. It is a theorem of real analysis that any extension of $f$ to the closed interval $[a,b]$ is integrable and the value of the resulting integral does not depend on the values of the extension at the endpoints of the interval. Is it appropriate to simply refer to "the definite integral of $f$ from $a$ to $b$" without explaining that we really mean the definite integral of an arbitrary extension of $f$ to $[a,b]$? I have seen it done before, as in the statement of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: Integrating Derivatives (see below), but is this abuse of terminology common?

Example - (Fitzpatrick, Theorem 6.22, pp 161-162):

> Let the function $F\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and be differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$. Moreover, suppose that its derivative
>   $$
> F'\colon (a,b)\to \mathbb R \text{ is both continuous and bounded.}
> $$
>   Then
>   $$
> \int_a^b F'(x)\, dx = F(b) - F(a).
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is ok. For an integral the value of the function at any finite number of points does not matter and in particular the values $f(a), f(b)$ at the end-points of the interval $[a, b]$ have no role to play in defining the integral $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$. I don't think such *abuse of terminology* causes any problem.